# Different validators for Angular form field based on another field value

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form that has two fields: `searchType` and `number`. The field `searchType` can be '0' or '1' only. `number` is a number and number has some validation.

```
this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  searchType: ['0'],
  number: [
    undefined,
    [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6) ]
  ]
});
```

But now I want to add some specific validator for `number` only if `searchType` is 1. For example if `searchType` is 0 I have to use `[ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6) ]`, but if `searchType` is 1 I have to use `[ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.minLength(20)]`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a change event on your `searchType`, or then subscribe to `valueChanges` and then set the validators for your `number` form control.

```ts
searchtypeCtrl: FormControl;
numberCtrl: FormControl;

this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  searchType: ['0'],
  number: [undefined,[ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6) ]]
});
// set form controls to variables
this.searchTypeCtrl = this.searchForm.get('searchType');
this.numberCtrl = this.searchForm.get('number');
```

and the `valueChanges`. As mentioned you could also listen to some change event and call a method that checks the value of the `searchTypeCtrl` and updates validators accordingly.

```ts
searchTypeCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  value === 0  ?  this.numberCtrl.setValidators([..conditional validators..]) :
                  this.numberCtrl.setValidators([..conditional validators..])

  this.numberCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
})
```